# Form.Serialize with checkbox array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I'm submitting a form through JQuery by using the form.serialize method. But that same form has an array of checkboxes, which is dynamically genetrated by a PHP function
This is the form:

```
<form class="form" id="formNewClient" role="form">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active"><a href="#clientdata" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Dados Cliente</a></li>
                <li><a href="#phoneparkdata" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> Dados Phonepark</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="clientdata">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="page-header"><h3>Dados Pessoais</h3></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                            <label for="name">Nome Completo:*</label>
                            <input type="text" name="clientName" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome Completo do Utilizador">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                            <label for="email">Email:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="clientEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Utilizador">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                            <label for="addressone">Morada:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="clientAddressone" class="form-control" placeholder="Morada do Utilizador">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row"> 
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="address2">Morada (cont.):</label>
                            <input type="text" name="clientAddresstwo" class="form-control" placeholder="Morada do Utilizador (cont.)">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                            <label for="postalcode">Código Postal:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="clientCPostal" class="form-control" placeholder="Código Postal">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                            <label for="city">Localidade:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="clientCity" class="form-control" placeholder="Localidade">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label for="clientNif">NIF</label>
                            <input type="text" name="clientNif" class="form-control " placeholder="NIF">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label for="clientBirthdate">Data de Nascimento</label>
                            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='inputendDate' data-date-format="YYYY/MM/DD">
                <input type='text' name="clientBirthdate" class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
                </div>
                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label for="sex">Sexo:</label>
                            <br>
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadioSex" value="M">
                            Masculino
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadioSex" value="F">
                            Feminino
                        </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
        <!--END CLIENTDATA-->
        <div class="tab-pane" id="phoneparkdata">
            <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="page-header">
                                <h3>Dados Phonepark</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12"><h4>Documentos:</h4></div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label for="document">Tipo de Documento:</label>
                            <select name="documenttype" class="form-control">
                                <?php selectListDocuments();?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label for="documentNumber">Número do Documento:*</label>
                            <input type="text" name="documentNumber" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label for="documentNumber">Número do Documento (Secundário):</label>
                            <input type="text" name="documentNumberSec" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12"><h4>Comunicações:</h4></div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label for="phone1">Telemóvel:*</label>
                            <input type="text" name="clientPhonePri" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label for="phone2">Telemóvel Secundário:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="clientPhoneSec" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <h4>Perfil:</h4>
                            <label for="profile">Perfil(s) a utilizar:*</label>
                            <?php 
                                profileCheckBoxes();
                            ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="activationDate">Data de Activação:</label>
                            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='inputactivationDate' data-date-format="YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm">
                <input type='text' name="clientActivationTime" class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
                </div>
                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="limitDate">Data de Limite:</label>
                            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='inputendDate' data-date-format="YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm">
                <input type='text' name="clientDeactivationTime" class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
                </div>
                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--END PHONEPARKDATA-->    
            </div>
    <!--END TAB-CONTENT-->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 pull-right">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submitNewClient" id="submitNewClient"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Adicionar Cliente</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Cancelar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

And this is the php function that generates the checkboxes:

```
function profileCheckBoxes(){
$queryListProfiles = "SELECT * FROM perfil";
$listProfiles = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['dbc'],$queryListProfiles);
$numProfiles = mysqli_num_rows($listProfiles);
if($numProfiles !=""){
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($listProfiles)){
    ?>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row['id']?>" name="profiles[]">
      <?php echo $row['Nome']; ?>
    </label>
    <?php
  }
}
}
```

How can I submit the form with form.serialize in Jquery and in the PHP side process the checkbox so I can extract the values from the checkbox array?

Comment: Did you get any error during serialization?

Comment: @Madhu actually I don't get any error during serialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This jQuery documentation page explains how to use the serialize function:
http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

If you then pass the output to your php page using POST, in the PHP script the checked values will be stored in `$_POST['profiles']` as an array. So to loop through the values of the checked boxes you could use:

```
foreach ($_POST['profiles'] as $profile) {  
    //process code here
}
```

Comment: Using your solution this is the console.log() of my form.serialize
`clientName=Teste+EST&clientEmail=teste%40est.pt&clientAddressone=&clientAddresstwo=&clientCPostal=&clientCity=&clientNif=&clientBirthdate=&documenttype=BI&documentNumber=1231231&documentNumberSec=&clientPhonePri=31231231231&clientPhoneSec=&profiles=1&profiles=2&profiles=3&clientActivationTime=&clientDeactivationTime=&submitNewClient= `

Comment: Have you changed the names of your checkboxes from `profiles[]` to `profiles`? If you have, undo it! You need the square brackets so that PHP treats it as an array.
Once you have changed the name back your form.serialize function should return `profiles[]=1&profiles[]=2&profiles[]=3`. You can then pass the result of form.serialize into your php script using an AJAX request (`$.ajax({...})`) and `$_POST['profiles']` will be `[1, 2, 3]`.

Comment: Cowman Thank you, that was indeed correct, it's now working flawless. thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's form.serialize only pass checksboxes that are checked.
if you want all your checkboxes to get passed to your server consider to generate also hidden inputs to store those values.

I would also change the checkboxes name to "profiles"

Comment: Actually I'm only trying to obtain the value of the checked checkboxes, since those are the ones that build the connect between the profile and the user on this case.